# gradle does not fetch dependencies after upgrade from 5.1.1 to 6.4.1

Tags: gradle

I have several services that uses gradle 5.1.1 with java 8.

As we want to upgrade to Java 13, we first need to upgrade to gradle 6after doing so, some dependencies are not fetched.

Those dependencies are listed with `compile()` under a dependency which is our jar library and still built with gradle 5.1.1

our libraries are stored in a S3 bucket and we use shadowjar to generate the end jar.

---

**so, for example:**

I have project A which I want to upgrdae.
Project A has project B as a dependency (compile) 
Project B has google guava as a dependency (also with compile)

Now, project A, that under gradle 5.1.1 had fetched guava with no problems, alerting me that it is missing guava after upgrading to gradle 6.

I use local computer installed gradle (not wrapper).

Here are the important build.gradle parts:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }

    ext.ver = [
            'springboot': '2.2.0.RELEASE',
            'slf4j'     : '1.7.12'
    ]

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${ver.springboot}"
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.2.0'
        classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.5'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    testCompile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    runtime.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'

    compile.exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 10, 'seconds'
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 10, 'seconds'
}

dependencyManagement {
    applyMavenExclusions = false
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "s3://bucket"
        credentials(AwsCredentials) {
            accessKey = awsCredentials.AWSAccessKeyId
            secretKey = awsCredentials.AWSSecretKey
        }
        metadataSources {
            artifact()
        }
    }
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile("com.test:projectB:1.0.0")
     ...
}

import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.PropertiesFileTransformer

shadowJar {
    classifier = ''
    baseName = 'project-A'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.test.projectA.Starter'
    }
    mergeServiceFiles()
    append 'META-INF/spring.handlers'
    append 'META-INF/spring.schemas'
    append 'META-INF/spring.tooling'
    transform(PropertiesFileTransformer) {
        paths = ['META-INF/spring.factories']
        mergeStrategy = "append"
    }
}
```

Could this be because project B was not built with new gradle?

unfortunately, I cannot create a real reproducer as those libraries are real code of the company I work at.

Thanks and Regards,
Ido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `metadataSources` declaration of the `s3` bucket Maven repository is most likely the root cause why transitive dependencies of `projectB` are not resolved. The [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:supported_metadata_sources) is quite a bit vague here, but I *suspect* `artifact()` looks for the actual jar file only and not for the POM file, hence transitive dependency resolution is not performed. You should be able to see this behavior when running the build with switches `--info` and `--refresh-dependencies`.

Thankfully, this is quite easy to fix. Add `mavenPom()` and Gradle will try to resolve the POM first and with that, dependency resolution should be back to normal.

And while you're at it, you might want to read the [upgrading from Gradle 5 guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#changes_6.0) and get rid of the `compile` configuration in favor of `implementation`. You should be able to see a warning similar to this when running the build with `--warning-mode all`:

```
The compile configuration has been deprecated for dependency declaration. This will fail with an error in Gradle 7.0. Please use the implementation or api configuration instead. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#dependencies_should_no_longer_be_declared_using_the_compile_and_runtime_configurations
```

Comment: Did as you said and it worked. thanks.   Now I have another problem:

Comment: Project B has jedis dependency. On runtime I get: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/params/geo/GeoRadiusParam`

I can see jedis in my dependencies in intellij and I can see the GeoRadiusParam class too.

Any ideas?
Can this be connected to my pudblish to S3?  which has only the S3 credentials. no  `mavenPom()` and no `artifact()`

Comment: @IdoBarash Cannot tell from the information provided. Might be an issue with Project B. You may post a new question with more details.

Comment: found it.. thanks
It was regarding implementation and api functions.